# Upload to S3 directly from form

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload mp3 files to my S3 bucket. I read somewhere that the best way is to upload files from a html form directly to S3 without piping through a server. But I was wondering: is this approach safe? Isn't a server necessary for security reasons, like applying access keys etc?

Also I'm finding it rather difficult to make it work. The official explanation isn't very detailed I think.

I'm following this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html which is the official guide. I'm not sure that I'm doing it right. Could you please tell me if this is the right way and what I'm doing wrong:

**1. I fill out a Policy object**

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

- what is "x-amz-meta-uuid" and where do I find it?
- what do I write in "x-amz-credential" node?

**2. I base64 encode the Policy Object**

**3. I make the HTML page with upload form**

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" />
    Content-Type: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption" value="AES256" /> 
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20151229T000000Z" />

    Tags for File: 
    <input type="input"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<Base64-encoded policy string>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<signature-value>" />
    File: 
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

- It seems the form input values are the same as the newly created Policy object which I'm also referencing in the form. So how come I have to fill these out twice?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is AWS S3 pre-signed URL. Basically, steps are:

1) Server generates a pre-signed url (because it has aws key)

2) Server passes this pre-signed url to browser

3) Browser can upload file directly to s3 by this pre-signed url

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: This is not really an answer to my question!

Comment: Sorry that I didn't state it out clearly. I was trying to answer your question: " is this approach safe? Isn't a server necessary for security reasons, like applying access keys etc?". The key thing is you don't pass AWS access key to browser directly, but instead you can pass pre-signed URL and then browser can use that to upload to S3. This is another safer approach compared to the one you posted. This reference is a good example (https://www.terlici.com/2015/05/23/uploading-files-s3.html). Note at: "s3.getSignedUrl"